# Determine if a key sequence has already been assigned in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, keymapping, sublimetext3

Does Sublime Text (2|3) have an API method or some way of determining if a shortcut or hot key sequence has already been assigned? I have lots of plugins and macros installed, and when making new ones it can be difficult to determine what key sequence to assign it to so I don't conflict with something else. Key bindings can be assigned in `.sublime-keymap` files in `Packages/Default`, `Packages/User`, and whichever plugin wants to assign them. To make things more complicated, I work on three different OSes, and there are different keymaps for each platform. Do I have to keep manually searching all the keymap files myself, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might try installing and using [FindKeyConflicts](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts).

You can also open a console <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> and enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`. You can then enter your shortcut/key sequence and see what, if anything, is bound to it.