# Sublime Text 2 do not prompt for new file name

Tags: ide, sublimetext2

I got a problem with Sublime Text 2. It is always creating new, untitled file and never prompt for name while creating.

It does it for folders and I see on web tutorials that this should be default behavior also for files.

Does anybody had ever problem like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install [`SideBarEnhancements`](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) via <strike>package control</strike>, cloning the repo.

Then, if you are using OSX using `ctrl + shift + t` will create a new file, prompting you for a file name. For linux and windows, default is `ctrl + t`, I believe.

Comment: I have SideBarEnhancements, unfortunatelly your shortcut is bind to opening closed Tab.

Comment: I am suprised you didn't mention you had this package installed.  Why not use a new key mapping, then?  [See this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676623/determine-if-a-key-sequence-has-already-been-assigned-in-sublime-text/16676749#16676749) for more information.